ASP.NET Core redirect from controller and blocked by CORS policy
In the ASP.NET Core MVC project, I make a redirect from the controller to an external source after performing certain calculations
return Redirect(confirmation_url);

But the redirection does not occur and in the browser in the developer console I see

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'url' (redirected from 'https://localhost:44312/path') from origin 'https://localhost:44312' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

What is the reason for this behavior? And how can I add the required header before making a redirect?
I tried something like this
HttpContext.Request.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new StringValues("*"));

but it didn't work for me

the redirect will retain the previous origin... and the initial call must have been made with a non-simple request.  The site you are redirecting to is not explicitly allowing cross-origin calls from localhost:44312.  Can you include the initial request?

Firstly, this is the confirmation_url's application block the request. What's confirmation_url's application? Is it ASP.NET Core or else application?
